# How do I count specific JSON items in Bash, or another shell?

Tags: json, bash, shell, parsing, jq

I have JSON data in the following form:

```
{
"home": [{
  "pageid": "about yft",
  "pageData": "0908782"
},

{
  "pageData": "09897"
}]}
```

How do I get the total number of `home->pageid` items?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$curFileName ={{Path_of_json_file.json}}
appName0=$(cat $curFileName | jq -c '.["home"][]["pageid"]'  | sed 's/"//g');
${#appName0[@]} # to get the length of pageid but didn't success..
```

But it didn't return the desired results.

Answer (score 3):

Collect the `pageid` items of `"string"` type into an array, then return the length of the array:

```
n=$(jq '[.home[].pageid | select(type == "string")] | length' < file.json)
```

Alternatively, check if the items in the `home` array have `pageid`. If the item has the property, put `1` into the result array, otherwise put zero. Finally sum the zeroes and ones with `add` function:

```
n=$(jq '[.home[] | if has("pageid") then 1 else 0 end] | add' < file.json)
```

Here is how you should print the number:

```
printf '%d\n' "$n"
```

*Sample Output*

```
3
```

Comment: I would probably quote `"$num"` just to be showcasing good practices, despite the case where lack of quotes would be a cause a bug in this specific usage (ie. `IFS` with numeric digits in it) being unlikely.

Comment: BTW, isn't `-M` default whenever output is not to a TTY? So you shouldn't need it in the command substitution case (or if redirecting to a file... so, really, *ever*, IMHO).

Comment: WARNING: This answer (using ...["pageid"]) will count items that have no "pageid" key.

Comment: Do you see any drawbacks in the updated answer, @CharlesDuffy, @peak? The original answer actually matched the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41036841/2). I hope the OP will not bring new specifications the the question, again.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov - Your revised first answer is a reasonable interpretation of the question given its ambiguity and the nature of the sample input; your second answer has semantics that are closer to the question, but it's a very inefficient approach as it involves constructing (outer square brackets) an array of length n, whereas there's only a need to record the 1s. So you could write: if _ then 1 else empty end, or just: select(_) | 1

Answer (score 2):

The input as originally given by the OP was invalid, and also didn't include an object without .pageid.  In this response, the following JSON will be used:

```
{
  "home": [
    {
      "pageid": "about yft",
      "pageData": "0908782"
    },
    {
      "pageData": "09897"
    }
  ]
}
```

Consider now these two filters, both of which yield 1 for the above JSON:

```
[.home[] | select(has("pageid")) ] | length


[.home[] | .pageid//empty ] | length
```

If .home was huge, then a more efficient approach would be as follows:

```
def count(s): reduce s as $i(0; .+1);
count(.home[] | select(has("pageid")))
```

And here's an efficient, one-line variant:

```
reduce (.home[].pageid?//empty) as $x (0; .+1)
```

#### Counting the number of distinct items

To obtain the number of **distinct** `home->pageid` items, the simplest would be to use `unique|length` rather than `length`, e.g. in either of the first two solutions above.

Answer (score -2):

After doing lots of search get the best result which is given below

```
echo `cat $curFileName | jq '.["home"][]["pageid"]' | wc -l `
```

Where is:

- `$curFileName` = {{Path_of_json_file.json}}
- `.["home"][]["pageid"]` = target Json Object

json_file.json :

```
{
  "home": [
    {
      "pageid": "about yft",
      "pageData": "0908782"
    },
    {
      "pageData": "09897"
    }
  ]
}
```

for more 
http://www.compciv.org/recipes/cli/jq-for-parsing-json/

Comment: This is both slightly buggy (`cat $curFileName` needs to be `cat "$curFileName"` to work with filenames with spaces) and quite inefficient (having read from a FIFO from `cat` rather than direct from the file incurs a small cost, and making `jq` write content out to an output file to be counted separately by `wc -l` rather than doing the counting direct in `jq` incurs a larger one).

Comment: No need to  cat "$curFileName" it is working and tested and it is working, I got your point but  that is a variable so No need to be   cat "$curFileName" like that

Comment: You didn't test it with filenames with spaces. Just because something works in the limited cases you tested doesn't mean it's actually *correct*.

Comment: I didn't think bcoz I test it and it working with my automation project without any issues : eg : curFileName ="My_Json_Path.josn" and after that I type echo `cat $curFileName | jq '.["home"][]["pageid"]' | wc -l ` and got the value without any issues

Comment: Try pasting your one line of code into http://shellcheck.net/, and following the links behind the warnings it generates -- each has a wiki page describing *in detail* the best practice and reasoning behind it.

Comment: Again, does your automation project have filenames with spaces, or are you using a alternate IFS value (with characters that can exist in your filenames) in it? If the answer is "no", then you wouldn't have caught the relevant bugs, but just because you aren't catching them doesn't mean they aren't there. Again, see shellcheck's results.

Comment: Have test it on my mac terminal and didn't get any warning well thanks for share this url (shellcheck.net) I try but didn't use it before so let be problem to find out how it work...

Comment: there is no filenames with spaces, it is like curFileName="My_Json_Path.josn"

Comment: **That's my point**. If you don't test with a filename with spaces, then you don't find the bugs that happen only given such a name (or in some other cases -- if you had `IFS=_` or `IFS=.`, you'd have the same problem with the names you're already testing with).